# How do I get an access token on behalf of user in Azure OIDC

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We have a single page application that calls an API (This has its own scope). The API now wants information about the user.

Does Graph API need an access token that's opaque?

Any ideas on how to get an access token to call a Graph API on behalf of the user?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are looking for  the scenario of OBO flow to call MS Graph please go through the step by step tutorial

1. [To configure the code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore)
2. [Acquire a token for the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-acquire-token?tabs=aspnetcore)
3. [Call Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-call-api?tabs=aspnetcore)

Comment: I wasnt sure if OBO is the option I should use. I will give this a shot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems better to use [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to obtain access token for single page application.

> It's used to perform authentication and authorization in the majority
> of app types, including **single page apps**, web apps, and natively
> installed apps. The flow enables apps to securely acquire
> access_tokens that can be used to access resources secured by the
> Microsoft identity platform endpoint, as well as refresh tokens to get
> additional access_tokens, and ID tokens for the signed in user.

You could refer to the tutorial: [Sign in users and call the Microsoft Graph API from a JavaScript single-page app (SPA) using auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-auth-code).